# How do I get a css file to be reflect any updates in localhost on xampp?

Tags: css, xampp, localhost

I have an index.html and a CSS file that are part of a wider project I am working on and it appears that any amendments I make to the CSS file is not reflected in the localhost server. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will request the html files and won't always load the newest files because they are being pulled out of the cache. The best way to reset the cache is to do ctrl + shift + r.

Comment: Thank you. you are a genius :) Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is a cache issue. Simple test:
Reload the page using ctrl+f5 on your keyboard. If the css updates, then your browser is (correctly, usually) caching the css file.

If this is the case, you can set up xampp to send a no cache header always or disable caching on your browser. Depending on your browser, you may be able to disable the cache on a specific domain, so all files served by localhost are not cached.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried Hans suggestion and it worked. Thank you kindly.